# How to select top 5 Read XML document stored in SQL Server with XML datatype?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sql-server-2008

I need to read XML documents stored in SQL Server 2008 R2 with XML datatype.

Actually I am new to it. I am using SQL Server 2008 and ASP.NET 4.0. I am storing Data table (.NET) at SQL side in XML form.

This is an example of the XML being stored in the SQL Server in a table column. Like I have more than 10 columns, here I need to select the 4 columns last inserted `<Data />`

```
"really a nice solution file"
```

from below xml file could u please help

Thanks In advance

```
<Section xml:space="aligned" Paste="False" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com">
<Para FontSize="11" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" TextAlignment="Left">
<Data Text="really a nice solution, but i have an other issue that  want to create its xml file" />
</Para>
</Section>

<Section xml:space="aligned" Paste="False" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com">
<Para FontSize="11" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" TextAlignment="Left">
<Data Text="really a nice solution file" />
</Para>
</Section>
```

This is my table structure

```
ID       Name         XMLContent                                  CreatedDate                   |       Modified
--------|------------|------------------|------------------------|-----------------------------------------
1       | CATEGORYID |<Section xml:space="aligned" Paste="False".|    |2011-04-05 12:28:15.030  |      
2       |    114     |<Section xml:space="aligned" Paste="False".|2011-04-05 12:28:15.030       |
```

i need to get the answer like

```
1   |really a nice solution, but i have an other issue that  want to create its xml file| 
2   |really a nice solution, |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a table with an `ID` and a `XmlData` column (adapt as needed - you should really post your table structures when asking such questions!), you can use something like this:

```
DECLARE @xmltbl TABLE (ID INT, XmlData XML)

INSERT INTO @xmltbl(ID, XmlData) 
VALUES(1, '<Section xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com">
<Para FontSize="11" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" TextAlignment="Left">
<Data Text="really a nice solution, but i have an other issue that  want to create its xml file" /></Para></Section>'), 
(2, '<Section xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com">
<Para FontSize="11" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" TextAlignment="Left">
<Data Text="really a nice solution file" /></Para></Section> ');

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com')
SELECT 
    ID,
    DataText = XmlData.value('(/Section/Para/Data/@Text)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
FROM @xmltbl
```

I had to remove the `xml:space="aligned" Paste="False"` from your XML since it caused errors.

This gives you an output of:

```
ID  DataText
1   really a nice solution, but i have an other issue that  want to create its xml file
2   really a nice solution file
```

And if you need the *top 5 rows by date added*, then just change your select to something like:

```
SELECT TOP 5 
    ID, .....
FROM ......
ORDER BY 
    -- order by DateAdded descending - giving you the most recent 5 rows
    DateAdded DESC
```

**Update:** tried to adapt to your table structure - name of your table is still unknown so you'll need to **adapt** `dbo.YourTableName` to whatever your table really is called!

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com')
SELECT TOP 5
    ID,
    XmlContent.value('(/Section/Para/Data/@Text)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
FROM dbo.YourTableName
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

Comment: thnaks for Reply but i am getting some error like  XmlData.value  can not fine i had  added my table stracture could pleas modify the Query as of my table stracture it's an humble request urgent for me Thanks mr marc_s

Comment: i am very thank full to you if possible plase modify the above query as of my table stracture

Comment: SELECT TOP 5 
    ID,Name, XMLContent= XMLContent.value('(/Section/Para/Data/@Text)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
FROM  News 
ORDER BY     
    DateCreated DESC  i had written is it right

Comment: thanks for modify but i have issue it is saying      Cannot find either column “XMLContent” or the user-defined function or aggregate “XMlContent.value”, or the name is ambiguous

Comment: Sorry - typo - should be `XmlContent` (not `XmlContext`)